# Manipulating fields and values in dict and transforming into tuples in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like

```
{'2016-05-30':{
    'go':((1, 2, 3, 4),), 
    'stop':((5, 6, 7, 8),)}, 
 '2016-05-31': {
    'go':((11, 12, 13, 14),), 
    'stop':((15, 16, 17, 18),)}}
```

and I have a list of state: `['state1', 'state2', 'state3', 'state4']`

I'm trying to get an output that looks like `(state, date, value)`

I can do it by running bunch of `for` loops:

```
some_list=[]
state = ['state1', 'state2', 'state3', 'state4']
data = {'2016-05-30':{
    'go':((1, 2, 3, 4),), 
    'stop':((5, 6, 7, 8),)}, 
 '2016-05-31': {
    'go':((11, 12, 13, 14),), 
    'stop':((15, 16, 17, 18),)}}
for d in data:
    for vals in data.values():
        for val in vals.get('go'):
            if val:
                for k,v in zip(state, val):
                    some_list.append((k, d, v))
```

It's very brute force, and I'm wondering if there's a more clever way/pythonic way to do it

EDIT: okay, using actually values now instead of fake values (for most part). Should be clearer. Code should be able to be copypasta-ed

Comment: If you want pythonic, list comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @leekaiinthesky I might be able to do list comprehension on the last part of the code (append), but I still have trouble getting rid of other for loops

Comment: It would be nice if you included valid Python code in question. Makes working with it easier.

Comment: @JonSurrell I can add my source dict. Is that what you're looking for? Otherwise this code is already working (except that .get statement)

Comment: @JChao, your dict consists of bunch of undefined variables: `date1`, `field1`, `value1`, etc. - that is what Jon Surrell meant

Comment: @JChao Yes, exactly that. In general try to include code that can be copy/pasted. Save us the time of having to recreate your data structure.

Comment: do `state1`, `state2` ... have anything to do with `field1`, `field2`, ...? also, what is `'field'`? What `field` do you want?

Comment: Alright guys sorry for the confusion and bad example. Here's the updated question and it includes complete raw input. thanks for the help once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I think that you want, using list comprehensions,

```
some_list = [[s, d, v] for d in data for vals in data[d]['go'] for s, v in zip(state, vals)]

# [['state1', '2016-05-31', 11],
#  ['state2', '2016-05-31', 12],
#  ['state3', '2016-05-31', 13],
#  ['state4', '2016-05-31', 14],
#  ['state1', '2016-05-30', 1],
#  ['state2', '2016-05-30', 2],
#  ['state3', '2016-05-30', 3],
#  ['state4', '2016-05-30', 4]]
```

If the field 'go' is not always present, you can use

```
[[s, d, v] for d in data for f in data[d] for vals in data[d][f] for s, v in zip(state, vals) if f == 'go']
```

Comment: @JChao is this not what you are after?

Comment: for some reason it's not running on my code. I'm gonna tweak around and see what i can get, but I do believe this is the answer. Will mark as answer. thanks.